# Unknown error executing command (empty document returned), when executing aggregate in mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to group by in mongodb: my code below:

```
$m = new MongoClient("localhost");
$c = $m->selectDB("grl_db")->selectCollection("USER_TBL");
$data = array (
    'title' => 'this is my title',
    'author' => 'bob',
    'posted' => new MongoDate,
    'pageViews' => 5,
    'tags' => array ( 'fun', 'good', 'fun' ),
    'comments' => array (
      array (
        'author' => 'joe',
        'text' => 'this is cool',
      ),
      array (
        'author' => 'sam',
        'text' => 'this is bad',
      ),
    ),
    'other' =>array (
      'foo' => 5,
    ),
);
$d = $c->insert($data, array("w" => 1));

$ops = array(
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "author" => 1,
            "tags"   => 1,
        )
    ),
    array('$unwind' => '$tags'),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            "_id" => array("tags" => '$tags'),
            "authors" => array('$addToSet' => '$author'),
        ),
    ),
);
$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
```

But err occurs:

> Type: MongoResultException
>
> Message: Unknown error executing command (empty document
>   returned)
>
> Filename:
>   D:\Projects\sns\grl1.0\trunk\src\server\GRL\application\models\user_model.php
>
> Line Number: 195

How can i solve this problem. Please help me!!!

Comment: The "author" field you appear to want is also within it's own array of `"comments"`. So what are you expecting to see? You really want both authors returned for each tag of `"fun"` and `"good"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is php version.
To aggregate, php version will be over 5.6.1
I think your php version may be below 5.6. 
Please use xampp higher version.

Comment: thank you for your attention. i tried it but occur the same err,